# multiple column sorting in jtable with c# and JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

i want to sort columns by two fields in `jtable` 
[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt8r1.png)

in this image there are multiple fields and what I want to do is I want to sort this table by `partyname` and then by `inquirydate` or by site name and inquiry date. why I need this because I want sorted records for particular site and then by date for newly added records.

jtable loaded by this code.

```
  title: 'Inquiry List',
  sorting: true,
  multiSorting: true,
  selecting: true, //Enable selecting
  multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
  selectingCheckboxes: true,
  paging: true,
  pageSize: 10,
  defaultSorting: 'NextFollowedUpDate DESC',
  //Initialize validation logic when a form is created
  formCreated: function (event, data) {//other code}
```

Is it possible if yes how to do this?

Comment: i haven't any idea what to do for multiple sorting in jtable i have searched on the internet for it but can't find anything then i asked this question

Comment: The issue is not that you didn't do your research. The issue is that you want others to solve your problem without even showing that you have tried yourself first.

Comment: thats true but i don't have any idea what to do then how should i try? i have read jtable documentation for sorting, i didn't find anything.